# How to manipulate elevation colour ramp in Potree?

Tags: dem, lidar, visualisation, color-ramp, potree

I would like to render bare earth LiDAR data with a colour ramp using natural colors instead of vibrant blues to yellow to red.

Does anyone know how to manipulate Potree to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for "potree.Gradient" in the file potree.js

The Gradient is a collection of six colourvalues. Each value is the RGB Value divided by 255.

```
Potree.Gradients = {
    RAINBOW: [
        [0, new THREE.Color(0.278, 0, 0.714)],
        [1/6, new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1)],
        [2/6, new THREE.Color(0, 1, 1)],
        [3/6, new THREE.Color(0, 1, 0)],
        [4/6, new THREE.Color(1, 1, 0)],
        [5/6, new THREE.Color(1, 0.64, 0)],
        [1, new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0)]
    ],
    ...
```

Write new colours in, delete cache and enjoy the scene

Comment: To add to this, you can actually define any number of gradient stops you want and you can change it at runtime using:

    viewer.scene.pointclouds[0].material.gradient = [
     [0.1, new THREE.Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
     [0.9, new THREE.Color(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)]
    ]